# query condition - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote code only on transact sql . I want to write this query in oracle sql. But it doesn't work . the main problem that I can't write my select parameters in the where condition . How to avoid this problem . My query ,

```
 select t.*, 
 count(*) over(partition by t.el1_code) cnt ,
 count(*) over(partition by t.el1_code, t.el1_valid) cnt1 ,
 concat(t.el1_name,t.el1_sname) str,
 max(concat(t.el1_name,t.el1_sname)) over(partition by t.el1_code) str_check
 from tasuser.coda_element_1 t
 )tt


 —where tt.cnt>1 and (tt.el1_valid=0 or (tt.el1_valid=1 and cnt=cnt1 and     
  str<>str_check) )
  where not  (tt.cnt>1 and (tt.el1_valid=0 or (tt.el1_valid=1 and    
  cnt=cnt1       and 
  str<>str_check)))
```

Comment: What's the PL in your title? Are you confusing Oracle / Oracle SQL with PL/SQL, a procedural programming language? There's nothing related to PL/SQL in your question. I will edit your title, but please pay more attention to details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use derived table/inline view:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
 select t.*, 
 count(*) over(partition by t.el1_code) cnt ,
 count(*) over(partition by t.el1_code, t.el1_valid) cnt1 ,
 concat(t.el1_name,t.el1_sname) str,
 max(concat(t.el1_name,t.el1_sname)) over(partition by t.el1_code) str_check
 from tasuser.coda_element_1 t
 )  tt
WHERE tt.conditions....
```

or `common table expression`:

```
WITH cte AS (
select t.*, 
     count(*) over(partition by t.el1_code) cnt ,
     count(*) over(partition by t.el1_code, t.el1_valid) cnt1 ,
     concat(t.el1_name,t.el1_sname) str,
     max(concat(t.el1_name,t.el1_sname)) over(partition by t.el1_code) str_check
     from tasuser.coda_element_1 t

)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE conditions ...
```